# Vue: pass value of methodA to methodB

Tags: vue.js, methods

Im trying to get the value of classlists into my uScore but it's giving me an error.
 How can i pass the value  of method `displayClasslists` to `uScore`

```
 methods: {
    displayClasslists() {
      this.$Progress.start();
      axios
        .get("/api/labview/" + this.$route.params.placeName)
        .then(({ data }) => this.$Progress.finish((this.classlists = data)));
    },
    uScore: function() {
      const elements = this.classlists.map(e => e.id);
      console.log(elements);
    }
  },
```

this is what i get:
`[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.classlists.map is not a function"`
This is my json **classlists**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a some suggestions:

1. Because `uScore` doesn't take any arguments and it depends only on `classlists`, then it should probably be a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).
2. Your current implementation of `uScore` doesn't return anything.
3. You should initialize `classlists` to be an empty array to avoid the error.

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return { classlists: [] };
  },
  computed: {
    uScore() {
      return this.classlists.map(e => e.id);
    },
  },
  methods: {
    displayClasslists() {
      this.$Progress.start();
      axios.get(`/api/labview/${this.$route.params.placeName}`).then(({ data }) => {
        this.classlists = data;
        this.$Progress.finish();
      });
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: thanks. this works. in my other code i'm using the click button. tha's why i inserted my uScore to my methods